# Python unicode woes

Tags: python, unicode

What is the correct way to convert '\xbb' into a unicode string? I have tried the following and only get UnicodeDecodeError:

```
unicode('\xbb', 'utf-8')

'\xbb'.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: It is part of a file that someone pasted from Word (so its a *str*). If you type print u'\xbb' you get the double arrow (>>) character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it comes from Word it's probably CP1252.

```
>>> print '\xbb'.decode('cp1252')
»
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be Latin-1 encoded. You should use:

unicode('\xbb', 'Latin-1')

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do. But in Python3 all strings are unicode per default. In Python2.X you have to use `u'my unicode string \xbb'` (or double, tripple quoted) to get unicode strings. When you want to print unicode strings you have to encode them in character set that is supported on the output device, eg. the terminal. `u'my unicode string \xbb'.endoce('iso-8859-1')` for instance.